# Dynamic Programming solution for Knapsack Problem with a constraint

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

How do I modify the DP algorithm for a knapsack problem with the constraint, that the next item to be taken has to have more profit than the previous one.

### To elaborate:

We have a lot of sushi on a table.
•They are arranged into a line.
Each sushi has a quality value (higher if it tastes better)
The quality values of sushi are distinct.
many kinds of sushi

•Find a way to take sushi such that
(1) total quality value is maximized, and
(2) the quality value of sushi taken is increasing
i.e. when you take a sushi A, you must next take a
sushi B better than A.
•Your algorithm should run in O(n2) time

Comment: `O(n^2)`? Why not just sort it (`O(nlogn)`) and then take in increase order?

Comment: In DP, we'll have to construct a 2D matrix, to obtain an optimal solution, we'll have to fill this matrix which costs O(N^2) in all cases. Are there any alternatives to sorting the items based on their value ?

Comment: So what you missing in your question description is that sushi can be taken only at their order (1..n)

Comment: Yes,I guess so !!

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-increasing-subsequence-dp-14/